# Parsing String read from a text file to Integer

Tags: java

I have a simple program where i read from a text file. Text file contains a number `99`. I read this number using a method named `readFile`. After reading it, i then call `writeFile` method which increments the number read from the text file by `1` and the again saves it in the text file.

**Method to read from file**

```
public void readFile() {

    String line = "";

    try(FileReader fr = new FileReader("Room Number.txt"); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {

       while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           roomNumberField.setText(line);
       }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    writeFile(line);
}
```

**Problem**

As you can see in the above method, i am reading the data from file in a `String` variable `line` and at the end of the method, i call `writeFile` method and pass the `line` variable in to this method. In the `writeFile` method, before i can increment the `line` variable by `1`, i have to parse it as `int` but doing so throws `NumberFormatException`. Now in my case, this exception will only be thrown only if `line` cannot be parsed as an `int`. At first i thought it could be because of `line` variable containing any `space`, so i called `trim` method on it which then threw `NullPointerException` which led me to believe that `line` is `null`.

**Question** is, why is `line` variable null ? it is initialized in `while loop` so how can it be null at the end of the method ?

**PS.** Number is read from the file correctly and if i move `writeFile(line);` inside `while loop` of `readFile` method, it doesn't throws any exception and my program works as it should.

Comment: Print the line, and you'll know. Or use your debugger.

Comment: i have and it correctly prints the number read from file

Comment: Then you're not parsing where you should parse. Post the code producing the error. And post the complete stack trace of the exception. Don't force us to guess what you're doing, and t guess what and where the error happens. If the file is supposed to contain a single line, why do you even use a while loop?

Comment: You literally loop until line becomes null. What exactly is tripping you up here?

Comment: @MadPhysicist exactly... Silly of me to miss such a simple thing

Comment: Save the last line with `last = line` at the end of the loop. Print that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things. Your call to `writeFile()` should be inside the try block since there is no point in running it if the read fails.

Also your error is because

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           roomNumberField.setText(line);
       }
```

This loop runs until `line == null`. So after it exits (before calling `writeFile()`) the value will be `null`.

Either you want to write every line then `writeFile` should be in the loop or you need to figure out which line you want and save it.

Answer (score 1):

answer is simple when `line` get equals to `null` in

`while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {`

while loop breaks and `line` has `null` value at this spot outside the loop. while inside the loop `line` has always some values because it is inside the loop :).